# DateValue and Format in a single formula

Tags: excel, vba, date, format, filenames

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out a dynamic filename problem.

I'm trying to extract the 6-digit date from a cell(J2) that includes time data, and use it to save my filename. The cell is formatted as "General".

The only formula I can get to work is this manual formula using an unoccupied cell (W2), and then deleting (ugly, I know):

```
Range("W2").Formula = "=DateValue(J2)"
RefDate = Format(Range("W2"), "m-d-yy")
NameofFile = "On Time Departure " & RefDate
Range("W2").Delete
```

The cell data is this

1/8/2015 2:00:00.000000 AM

I've tried nesting a DateValue function inside a Format function, but can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `J2` formatted as a Date or a String (Text)?

Comment: Ah, good point. That would make sense why he is using the `DATEVALUE` function then.

Comment: It's formatted as "General", but passes the "IsNumeric" test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim RefDate As Date
RefDate = Range("J2").Value
NameofFile = "On Time Departure " & Format(RefDate, "m-d-yy")
```

**EDIT**

If J2 contains a string and not a date, like Christmas007 noted, try this:

```
Dim curDate As String
Dim RefDate As Date

curDate = Range("J2").Value
RefDate = DateValue(Left(curDate, InStr(curDate, " ")))
NameofFile = "On Time Departure " & Format(RefDate, "m-d-yy")
```

Comment: I get a "Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed".

Comment: My God! It worked! I'm not familiar with InStr. Did you just look from left to right until you found a space?

Comment: @KarlDrews Yup, you got it!

Comment: @KarlDrews No problem! Make sure to mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you so that future visitors can see what worked.